# AWK - getting the min date/time on a computed command output

Tags: unix, awk, sh

I'm running a command to get the below output:

```
 bash-3.2$ /usr/g1_listuser

 Licensed(UDT+CP)/Effective      Udt     Sql     iPhtm   Pooled          Total

 (  25 + 2   ) / 27          5       0       0       0               5

 UDTNO USRNBR     UID  USRNAME USRTYPE              TTY         TIME        DATE

 1  14310   10889 webspher phantom             none     08:46:13 Feb 16 2017
 2   8327   10889 webspher phantom             none     23:45:21 Feb 15 2017
 6  26704   30797  t576278     udt            pts/1     04:21:29 Feb 16 2017
 7   8735   10889 webspher phantom             none     23:45:25 Feb 15 2017
 8  29590   10889 webspher phantom             none     03:34:29 Feb 16 2017
 9  29340   10889 webspher phantom             none     09:47:34 Feb 16 2017
 10  28627   10889 webspher phantom             none     09:47:19 Feb 16 2017
 11   9850   10889 webspher phantom             none     23:45:41 Feb 15 2017
 12  28805   10889 webspher phantom             none     09:47:24 Feb 16 2017
 13   8957   10889 webspher phantom             none     23:45:29 Feb 15 2017
 14   3487   10889 webspher phantom             none     09:47:20 Feb 14 2017
 15  24327   32027  p101468     udt            pts/3     15:00:12 Feb 15 2017
 16  29631   10889 webspher phantom             none     09:47:38 Feb 16 2017
 18   9644   10889 webspher phantom             none     23:45:36 Feb 15 2017
 20  29073   10889 webspher phantom             none     03:34:25 Feb 16 2017
 21  29838   10889 webspher phantom             none     03:34:33 Feb 16 2017
 22  26728   10889 webspher     udt             none     08:00:18 Feb 13 2017
 23  21835   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:42 Feb 16 2017
 25  12188   10889 webspher phantom             none     08:45:33 Feb 16 2017
 26   1138   10889 webspher phantom             none     03:34:47 Feb 16 2017
 27  21458   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:37 Feb 16 2017
 28  20834   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:29 Feb 16 2017
 29  20961   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:32 Feb 16 2017
 30   1561   10889 webspher phantom             none     03:34:51 Feb 16 2017
  31   7668   10889 webspher phantom             none     04:02:21 Feb 16 2017
  32  20998   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:33 Feb 16 2017
  33  21461   10889 webspher phantom             none     02:00:37 Feb 16 2017
 41  10980   10889 webspher     udt             none     09:00:39 Feb 13 2017
 42   3276   10889 webspher phantom             none     04:00:43 Feb 16 2017
 43  12985   10889 webspher     udt             none     04:07:30 Feb 15 2017
```

The result I'm trying to get is a count per USRNAME and min date/time associated, I built the below command:

```
/usr/g1_listuser | grep -v 'Licensed' | grep -v '(' | grep -v 'UDTNO' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=SUBSEP=" "}{arr[$4]+=1;date=$7$8$9$10;min_date="999999999";if(min_date>date){min_date=date};}END {for (i in arr) if (i != null) print i,min_date,arr[i];}'
```

That output the below:

```
webspher  31
p101468  1
t576278  1
```

Which doesn't display the date and time properly. Any help is welcome.

Machine: sun4u sparc 5.10 Generic_150400-32

Comment: youness: Please let us know what you are trying to achieve here? What is the expected output, provide some sample expected output in your post please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I'm trying to display the minimum date, output desired is:

webspher   08:00:18 Feb 13 2017   31
p101468     15:00:12 Feb 15 2017   1
t576278      04:21:29 Feb 16 2017   1

Comment: youness: Could you please your actual POST with code tags, will be eaiser to understand then.

Comment: I do need the code to be in one line command, hence the display, thank you.